# Manipulating android activity window using renderscript?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, renderscript

I am wondering if it possible to use Android renderscript to manipulate activity windows. For example if it is possible to implement something like  [3dCarousel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2caXMF-ud8), with activity running in every window?

I was researching for a long time, and all the examples I found are for manipulating bitmaps on the screen. If it is true, and renderscript is only meant for images, than what is used in [SPB Shell 3d](http://spb.com/android-software/shell), or these panels aren't actual acitivites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear to me that those are activities. To answer your question directly, to the best of my knowledge there is no way to do what you want with renderscript as the nature of how it works prevents it from controlling activities. The control actually works the other way around... You could however build a series of fragments containing renderscript surface views, however the processing load of this would be horrific to say the least. I am unsure of how to take those fragments or activities and then draw a carousel.

What I *think * they are doing is using render script or open gl to draw a carousel and then placing the icon images where they need to be. But I have never made a home screen app so I could be and likely am mistaken in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also think SPB Shell 3d doesn't use full activities, but it is for sure little more complicated than icon images, may be these are some kind of widgets. Because if I will type something on the calculator frame, these digits will stay there even if I'll zoom out and rotate the carousel.

Comment: Another idea, do you think it is possible to implement something like this using html5? Would android 4.0 support this?

Comment: HTML5 carousel video: www.viddler.com/embed/3b57fbf9   at 4:40

Comment: I couldn't speak to HTML 5 support as I personally know almost nothing about it. I would suggest asking that as a separate question after researching it some. It is likely to get someone's attention.